# Access Export (Excel or .csv) is limited to 1750 rows

Tags: excel, csv, ms-access, export

I need to export a dataset to excel via .xls or .csv and there are only 1750 rows exported with each of the methods. The column count of the dataset is 15 but this should make no difference.

Is there any setting I need to change? Such a low number of rows is far from the 65k I read on google which causes problems.

I used the built-in Export to excel or text file function.

Thanks

Comment: *"I used the built-in Export to excel or text file function."* Then this looks like a general computing question and should be asked at https://superuser.com instead. Stack Overflow is for programming related questions.

Comment: I couldn't replicate the problem.  try the microsoft fix.  copy everything to new tables without calculated variables.  If that doesn't work copy the data to a new access database file as well.

Comment: Check the actual length of your data..maybe its only a few records but if you have ton of data on each field maybe you have hit some limit.in that case you should check Excel Automation